# Bluestacks clone instances from command line

Tags: automation, bluestacks

I would like to be able to clone bluestacks instances from command line.

I have tried to clone the folder where the image is but it is not enough

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Process Monitor to catch how it works:

```
"C:\Program Files\BlueStacks\HD-VmManager.exe" createinstance clone Android_499 Android_462 "{"cpu":1,"ram":1024,"dpi":"240","abi":15,"resolutionwidth":960,"resolutionheight":540}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot this question. I was able to clone the instance...

Well it is not exactly a clone..., what i do is create a instance and then I just copy the file from the original folder to the new instance folder, overwriting the file there (you will need to rename the file). With that you clone the instance.

Probably you can skip this step, but you will need to include stuff here and there but this is exactly what I wanted, clone an instance. Since you create the new instance with bluestack, all is done right and it is just the file.